# How to find instances of objects that share a common relationship to another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

My question can be illustrated as follows:

I've got three models, User, Genre and Concert.

Instances of both `User` and `Concert` may be associated with any number of `genres`, so they have join tables with `Genre`, with has_and_belongs_to_many relationships.

My goal is to implement a filter that'll take an instance of `User` and return every instance of `Concert` that is associated to one or more `genres` in common with said `User`.

My code:

*# concert.rb:*

```
class Concert < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

*# user.rb:*

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end
```

*# schema.rb:*

```
create_table "genres_concerts", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "genre_id", null: false
  t.bigint "concert_id", null: false
end

create_table "genres_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "genre_id", null: false
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.index ["genre_id", "user_id"], name: "index_genres_users_on_genre_id_and_user_id"
  t.index ["user_id", "genre_id"], name: "index_genres_users_on_user_id_and_genre_id"
end
```

So I can call `.genres` on instances of either, eg. `User.find(1).genres` returns

```
[#<Genre:0x00000001086f1068 id: 440, name: "rock", created_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.092415000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.092415000 UTC +00:00>,

#<Genre:0x00000001086f0bb8 id: 444, name: "jazz", created_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.115169000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.115169000 UTC +00:00>,

#<Genre:0x00000001086f0ac8 id: 418, name: "electronica", created_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:50:49.304427000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:50:49.304427000 UTC +00:00>]
```

and `Concert.find(1).genres` returns

```
[#<Genre:0x00000001086f1068 id: 440, name: "rock", created_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.092415000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:51:38.092415000 UTC +00:00>,

#<Genre:0x00000001086f1bc8 id: 469, name: "punk", created_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:50:49.304427000 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 17 Nov 2022 01:50:49.304427000 UTC +00:00>]
```

In the example above, the user with the `id: 1` is associated with genres named "rock", "jazz" and "electronica", so I'd be looking for every `Concert` that is associated to any of those.

After quite a bit of reading and searching I'm still stuck trying to figure this one out, so any input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
# new scope in models/concert.rb
scope :suggestions_for_user, ->(user) {
  joins(:genres).where(genres: { id: user.genres.select(:id) })
}
```

And use it like this:

```
user = User.find(...)
Concert.suggestions_for_user(user).distinct
```

Note the `distinct` will be needed because of the nature of the database join the might return duplicate concerts.

Comment: Thank you, spickermann, your suggestion seems to work! I was not familiar with defining scopes in models, will look into it. Is this the go-to approach in cases like mine, do you think?

Comment: Yes, I would consider this as the Rails-way to solve your problem.